# Regex to substitute string which begins with a specific word

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have a list of names:

```
Mr James
Mr Kolt
Tony jr
Mr Wilson
```

and I want to retrieve the names which begins with the word **Mr** and just substitute the name in a way where it is without the me the **Mr** in the name.

I'm using https://regex101.com/ substitution function.

The substitute output I want is:

```
James
Kolt
Tony jr
Wilson
```

where the Mr is omitted.

I tried using the () notation for grouping

```
^(Mr)(.*)$
```

and it seems to be matching, so in the Substitute field, I just added $2 and it seemed to work, but I'm not entirely sure if I'm doing it correctly as the output:

[image]

seemed to have a whitespace in front for the string that was matched. Would appreciate some help to point out some mistakes if I had made any.

Comment: I think a simple whitespace after Mr will do it. Try this : `^(Mr\s)(.*)$` 
If you want to handle multiple whitespaces you could use this: `^(Mr(\s)+)(.*)$` and substitute with `$3`

Comment: Match `^Mr\s+` and replace with empty string

Answer (score 0):

You need to put white space between the groups.
Now there is no space and this is why it came in the second group.